# For a given input search the .txt file and if the search found print the whole line

Tags: text-processing, scripting

[Input File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBAaZ0mBiPgMQP_M2Z-0FWW5h4nEQ359/view?usp=sharing) My `.txt` file contains these kind of content :

```
Tom Thatcher's Fortune, by Horatio Alger, Jr.                   56896
Paradise Lost, by John Milton                                      20
```

The first string is book name,second is author and the last one is book number. I want to print the whole line when someone search for the book number (if the book number matches).
I'm new to bash scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
grep BOOKNUMBER textfile.txt
```

should solve this.

If you want to avoid that searching for book number 96 also lists Tom Thatcher's Fortune you can use

```
grep '[[:space:]]BOOKNUMBER[[:space:]]*$' textfile.txt
```

instead.

---

As a script (save as `searchbook`)

```
#!/bin/bash

BOOKFILE=/path/to/bookfile.txt

BOOK=$1
if [[ -z "$BOOK" ]]; then 
    echo -n "Booknumber? "
    read BOOK
fi

grep '[[:space:]]'$BOOK'[[:space:]]*$' $BOOKFILE
```

You can then either run

```
searchbook BOOKNUMBER
```

or

```
searchbook
```

In the second case you will get prompted for the number.

Comment: Can you please solve it in script? I'm kind of confused of grep as I never work with it.Thanks

Comment: Just type it into a bash prompt, it won't break anything.

Comment: It works but it also print some other lines containing 20.I can differ those with my desired line is whitespace.There is some whitespace before the book number and I only want to print the line when it matches with the book number not some other line.How can I do that.You can take a look on my input file.I give link in above.Thanks sir.

Comment: I add 2 more space in the grep and it works fine now.Thanks

Comment: btw What the *$ sign means.If I want to search for a string what should I change in the grep line.Thanks

Comment: @shakib The $ matches the end of the line. To search for any string in any position just use `grep string file`.

Comment: It matches the first word in my string and print all with that first matching word but I want to print the line when the whole string match.What should I add in that case.

Comment: @NazmusShakib `grep 'my long string with several words' file`

Comment: The string was taken as input and I will pass the variable there.Book is the variable where I put the taken string from user [grep $BOOK $BOOKFILE]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
grep 56896 file.txt
```

If you wanted to script it, it could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile='/path/to/file.txt'

grep "$1" "$inputfile"
```

Which you would then run like:

```
$ ./script.sh 56896
```

Comment: I want to take input from user and then search the file with the input and if there is any match then print the whole line.My input file contains a lot of strings and integers.

Comment: @NazmusShakib: That is what the script would do

Answer (score 0):

To avoid catching book # `196` along with book # `96`, I suggest a similar but more terse usage of `grep`:

```
grep ' 96$' file.txt
```

The `$` symbol in regular expressions meaning 'the end of the text sample', so it will only match on the correct line.

This can also be put into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep " ${1}\$" /path/to/file.txt
```

This can also be done a bit more safely with `awk`:

```
awk -v book=96 '$NF == book {print}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the lines for which the last word is something, `awk` comes to mind:

```
awk '$NF == "123"' # string comparison
awk '$NF == 123'   # number comparison, would also match on 0123, 123.0, 1.23e2
awk '$NF == ENVIRON["ENVVAR"]' # number comparison if both $NF and $ENVVAR
                               # look like numbers, string otherwise
```

For `awk`, those *words* by default are blank-separated. Depending on the implementation *blank* may be only space or tab characters, some may include other Unicode blank characters if classified as such in the locale. The `busybox` `awk` implementation also includes vertical spacing characters including the carriage return character.

If your file is formatted with MS-DOS line delimiters, that is the CR LF sequence of characters as opposed to just LF, then except with busybox awk, the above won't work. And even with busybox awk, the output lines would still have those problematic control characters that shouldn't be there on Unix.

So you should preprocess the input with `dos2unix` or `d2u` to convert the line endings to Unix format.

```
< file.dos dos2unix | awk '$NF == 123'
```

Your input file looks like it's made of records that are separated by blank lines. If you want to print the full records for a book number, you could do:

```
export BOOKNUMBER=123
< file.dos dos2unix | awk -v RS= -F '\n' '
    field[split($1, field, " ")] == ENVIRON["BOOKNUMBER"]'
```

There, we set the *record separator*  to the empty string to enter the *paragraph mode* (records separated by blank lines), and the *field separator* to newline (aka LF) so the first line of each record is in `$1` (the first field). We split that first line with the special `" "` field separator which is the default *word* splitting into the `field` array. And then compare the last element of that array (`split()` returns the number of elements, so `field[split()]` is the last element) with the content of the `$BOOKNUMBER` environment variable.

Comment: awk '$NF == 123' is OK with GNU Awk 4.1.4 if the line end with crlf